# Итерация в запросе SQLite

Tags: python, sql

В БД два номера тлф, при общем запросе по цифре 9 как надо выдает оба номера в таком виде [(8981,), (8911,)], при итерации выдает только первый номер (8981,) и все.

```
def get_num(num):
    with sqlite3.connect("BasePers.db") as con:
        db = con.cursor()
        i = db.execute(f"SELECT PersonNumber FROM persons WHERE PersonNumber LIKE '%{num}%'").fetchall()
        for n in i:
            return n

print(get_num(9))
```

Если писать

```
for n in i.fetchone():
    return n
```

то выдает в идеале без скобок, но только первый номер

Comment: Поставьте `return i` вместо цикла

Comment: Попробуйте return list(i) вместо цикла

Comment: оба варианта выдают выдают [(8981,), (8911,)]

Comment: @Banki так же вы написали, что это поведение "как надо"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def get_num(num):
    with sqlite3.connect("BasePers.db") as con:
        db = con.cursor()
        i = db.execute(f"SELECT PersonNumber FROM persons WHERE PersonNumber LIKE '%{num}%'").fetchall()
        for n, *_ in i:
            yield n

print(list(get_num(9)))
```

**ИЛИ**

```py
def get_num(num):
    with sqlite3.connect("BasePers.db") as con:
        db = con.cursor()
        i = db.execute(f"SELECT PersonNumber FROM persons WHERE PersonNumber LIKE '%{num}%'").fetchall()
        return [n for n, *_ in i]

print(get_num(9))
```

Comment: Ооо, с этим можно рабоать, спасибо!!
Если не трудно объясните в чем была проблема, просто не тот метод использовал иль как?

Comment: @Banki, После первого return ваша функция завершается и второй итерации не происходит, кроме того, `fetchall()` возвращает список кортежей и Ваш вариант в шаге итерации имеет кортеж а не значение его элемента